# How was the ssd_mobilenet_v1 tflite model in TFHub trained?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

How do I find more info on how the [ssd_mobilenet_v1](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/default/1) tflite model on TFHub was trained?

Was it trained in such a way that made it easy to convert it to tflite by avoiding certain ops not supported by tflite?  Or was it trained normally, and then converted using the tflite converter with TF Select and the tips on this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37844#issuecomment-605336360)?

Also, does anyone know if there's an equivalent mobilenet tflite model trained on OpenImagesV6? If not, what's the best starting point for training one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about about the exact origin of the model, but looks like it does have TFLite-compatible ops. From my experience, the best place to start for TFLite-compatible SSD models is with the [TF2 Detection Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md). You can convert any of the SSD models using [these instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tf2.md).

To train your own model, you can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md) that leverage Google Cloud.